# for each loop in excel macros vba jumping alternate rows

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros, vba

I have the below code in vba. The rows in sheet5 from columns a5 to a20 are:

a5=Sweden

a6=Spain

a7=Russia

a8=Italy

a9=Germany

a10=Finland

a11=Norway

a12=Switzerland

a13=France

a14=Belgium

```
Set fillcolumnrange = Sheet5.Range("A5:A20")
i = 1
For Each Row In fillcolumnrange.Rows
 If Not Sheet5.Range("A" & i + 4) = "" Then
    MsgBox Row(i)
 End If
 i = i + 1
Next Row
```

But this code is prompting only alternate values ie.

Sweden

Russia

Germany

Norway

France

Can anyone please help me out find the bug in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were looping through the rows in your range and also advancing the variable `i` within your loop.
You can reference each variable that you are looping through.

Try this

```
Set fillcolumnrange = Sheet1.Range("A5:A20")
For Each cell In fillcolumnrange.Cells
 If Not cell = "" Then
    MsgBox cell
 End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Nice - you beat me to it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You've got a mixture of different types of loop.

Either do what Rick says.

Or use `i`:

```
Set fillcolumnrange = Sheet5.Range("A5:A20")
For i = 1 To fillcolumnrange.Rows.Count
    If Not Sheet5.Range("A" & i + 4) = "" Then
       MsgBox Sheet5.Cells(i + 4, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

Or maybe a `do-Loop`

```
Set fillcolumnrange = Sheet5.Range("A5:A20")
i = 1
do until i = fillcolumnrange.Rows.Count + 4
 If Not Sheet5.Range("A" & i + 4) = "" Then
    MsgBox Sheet5.Cells(i + 4, 1)
 End If
 i=i+1
Loop
```

(**EDIT** now tested and seem to run ok)

Comment: Showing type mismatch on line "For i = 1 to fillcolumnrange.Rows"

Answer (score 0):

Building on Rick's answer, here's the short version of the `For Each` loop:

```
For Each cell in fillcolumnrange.Cells
    If len(cell) <> 0 Then MsgBox cell
Next
```